# putting files in subdirectory while making tar

Tags: tar

I am trying to make a tar file. I have 2 folders that I need to tar. let me clear my question.

```
folder 1. /temp1
folder 2. /temp1
```

now I want my tar output to be such that when i untar it i get

```
 /temp1/* (stuff of temp1)
 /temp1/temp2/* (temp2 and subdirectories inside temp1).
```

Right now I am copying temp2 into temp1 and than tarring it. Can anyone suggest me to do in a way that I don't have to copy the stuff, As if I kill the process in between I will be left some of temp2's stuff inside temp1.

Answer (score 2):

Symlink temp2 into temp1, and then tell tar to dereference (follow) the symlink with the `-h` or `--dereference` option.

e.g.

```sh
cd temp1
ln -s ../temp2/ .
cd ..
tar cvz -h -f example.tar.gz ./temp1
rm -f temp1/temp2
```

This will make a tar archive with `./temp2` beneath the `./temp1` directory (i.e. `./temp1/temp2`)

I can't remember if this `-h` option is a GNU extension or not.  If you're not using GNU `tar`, test carefully before using.

If you care about the modification timestamp of temp1, then use `touch -r`:

```
touch -r temp1 temp1-modtime
cd temp1
ln -s ../temp2/ .
cd ..
touch -r temp1-modtime temp1
tar cvz -h -f example.tar.gz ./temp1
rm -f temp1/temp2
touch -r temp1-modtime temp1
rm -f temp1-modtime
```

Comment: This worked but I think this is same as copying as I have to unlink after making tar to keep the original. I needed something that can be used without modifying the original. However by your approach space wont be a problem. so that's a plus. But if you can suggest something which doesn't modify the temp1 directory, then that will be useful.  Thanks.

Comment: @LokeshSharma *I needed something that can be used without modifying the original.*  Then make two tar files and `cd` into `temp1` to untar `temp2`.

Comment: creating and removing a symlink is also a lot faster than copying and later deleting a directory full of files.   Aside from the fact that it changes the modtime of `temp1` (which could be fixed with `touch -r` if necessary), i don't see any downside to using a symlink for this - it's simple, it works, it's fast, and it's not expensive in terms of resources (time, disk, cpu power).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with tar's transform option, which does a sed find and replace on the path names as they're processed into the archive.

I think what you want is:

```
tar -cf output.tar --transform 's,^temp2,temp1/temp2,' temp1 temp2
```

This will match any paths which start with `temp2` and rewrite them as `temp1/temp2`. It will not match and therefore not modify any paths which begin with `temp1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use tar append function with some tricks.
Something like this?

```
$ mkdir temp3; mkdir temp3/temp1    # create another, empty temp1 dir
$ ln temp2 temp3/temp1/temp2        # link temp2 into fake temp1
```

and then...

```
$ tar cf example.tar temp1      # 1st part of archive without temp2
$ cd temp3
$ tar rf ../example.tar temp1   # append temp2 as subfolder of temp1 to archive
```

Using hard links makes it possible to still have symlinks in the temp directories treated as symlinks. So -h not needed. Might keep you out of trouble later on.

You can also take a look at GNU tar extensions like --transform in combination with the append command. See also: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/tar-subdirectory-question-821074/

Comment: upon linking temp2, I got the following error `ln: ‘temp2’: hard link not allowed for directory`